# How to retrieve Intersected geometry of the polygons geometry POINT (lat,lng) input?

Tags: postgresql, spatial-analyst, st-intersects

I am passing a particular state (Indian states) latitude/longitude to the spatial query where it has to check intersection with the other table shapefiles polygon geometry. If that polygon is **within** the selected state polygons then it has to show all the state containing polygons.

Example situation I am trying is: suppose I have selected WEST BENGAL state its lat/lng will be passed and based on lat/lng intersection with other shapefile polygon has to done.

### Working out on the spatial query

```
SELECT  distinct ST_AsGeoJSON(a.geom) As geometry ,b.proj_sno,b.title,b.start_date,b.end_date,b.total_project_cost,c.proj_category, a.state ,ST_Within(a.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(87.85 22.98)'),4326))  FROM proj_mst b,
 shape_file a,proj_cat_mst c,india_states d
 where  a.proj_sno = b.proj_sno  and 
   a.proj_cat_id = c.proj_cat_id and a.proj_cat_id= 10
```

### Structure for Understanding

1.

```
-- Table: shape_file

-- DROP TABLE shape_file;

CREATE TABLE shape_file
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  area_ha double precision,
  perimeter double precision,
  type double precision,
  objectid double precision,
  cname character varying,
  state character varying,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
  proj_sno integer NOT NULL,
  proj_cat_id integer,
  statecode integer,
  CONSTRAINT shape_file_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid, proj_sno)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE shape_file
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

2.

```
-- Table: india_states

-- DROP TABLE india_states;

CREATE TABLE india_states
(
  gid serial NOT NULL,
  area double precision,
  perimeter double precision,
  indiasln_ integer,
  indiasln_i integer,
  state character varying(20),
  shape_leng numeric,
  shape_area numeric,
  geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326),
  latitude double precision,
  longitude double precision,
  statecode integer,
  CONSTRAINT india_states_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE india_states
  OWNER TO postgres;

-- Index: india_states_geom_idx

-- DROP INDEX india_states_geom_idx;

CREATE INDEX india_states_geom_idx
  ON india_states
  USING gist
  (geom);
```

3.

```
-- Table: proj_cat_mst

-- DROP TABLE proj_cat_mst;

CREATE TABLE proj_cat_mst
(
  proj_cat_id serial NOT NULL,
  proj_category character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT proj_cat_mst_pkey PRIMARY KEY (proj_cat_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE proj_cat_mst
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

4.

```
-- Table: proj_mst

-- DROP TABLE proj_mst;

CREATE TABLE proj_mst
(
  proj_sno integer NOT NULL,
  group_id integer,
  div_id integer,
  proj_id integer,
  proj_cat_id integer,
  start_date timestamp(6) without time zone,
  end_date timestamp(6) without time zone,
  duration character varying(200),
  status_id integer,
  funding_agency_id integer,
  pi_ec_no integer,
  title character varying(200),
  title_abbrev character varying(20),
  study_area character varying(100),
  fa_role character varying(300),
  total_project_cost double precision,
  prog_sofar character varying(3000),
  prog_so_far_percent integer,
  project_type character varying(100),
  objectives character varying(3000),
  deliverables character varying(3000),
  tasks character varying(3000),
  nrsc_role character varying(300),
  proj_weekly_report integer,
  CONSTRAINT proj_mst_new_pkey PRIMARY KEY (proj_sno)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE proj_mst
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Coordinates are entered in {X,Y} order. Use {longitude, latitude} in your constructor.

Comment: put the st_within function in the where statement?

Comment: Lean all about [JOIN statements](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/joins.html) to solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

You may simply be able to do it like this:

```
SELECT  
    distinct ST_AsGeoJSON(a.geom) As geometry,
    b.proj_sno,
    b.title,
    b.start_date,
    b.end_date,
    b.total_project_cost,
    c.proj_category,
    a.state,
FROM
    shape_file a,
    proj_mst b,
    proj_cat_mst c,
    india_states d
where
    a.proj_sno = b.proj_sno and 
    a.proj_cat_id = c.proj_cat_id and 
    a.proj_cat_id= 10 and
    ST_Within(a.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(87.85 22.98)'),4326))
```

But what you're actually trying to achieve isn't clear from your question.

You should perhaps look into how to do a [table join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html). This is a way of relating tables together, rather than selecting from many at once.

This way you can select your spatial object by intersection with the geometry, and find what states this spatial object are in. And those states could be joined by ID to your other tables, bringing their attributes across.

Comment: I have to work with polygon its not point.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the principle is the same regardless of the geometry type.